# Why can only certain variables be assigned using python debugger?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pdb

while debugging my code, I stumbled upon this behavior of pdb (see code below), where you can assign only certain types of variables. For clarification, I was using pandas DataFrames and wanted to assign the name of one of the columns to a new variable for quick reference, and no error was given doing just that. But when I wanted to use my new variable, I got different errors depending on how I used that variable. Where does this behavior come from and is it intended?

```py
(Pdb) pos_frame.columns[-1]
'Position 13'
(Pdb) a = pos_frame.columns[-1]
(Pdb) b = pos_frame[a].values
*** The specified object '= pos_frame[a].values' is not a function or was not found along sys.path.
(Pdb) pos_frame[a]
*** NameError: name 'a' is not defined
(Pdb) a
(Pdb) x = 4
(Pdb) x
4
```

*edit
some code for recreation

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pdb

# creating a DataFrame
col_list = [
    np.r_[0:50],
    np.r_[50:100]
    ]
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(col_list).transpose()
data_frame.columns = [f"Position {i}" for i in range(1, len(col_list)+1)]
pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: Will you please provide some code and the command to run the debugger for non-experts like me?

Comment: @richardec sure, give me a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a = ...` and `b = ...` are not recognized as Python statements, as `a` is an abbreviation of the `args` command and `b` is an abbreviation of the `break` command.

- `args` apparently ignores any arguments.
- `break` is rejecting `= pos_frame[a].values` as a function or file name, just like the following error message states.
- `pos_frame[a]` is unambiguously a Python (expression) statement, but as your attempt to define `a` earlier failed, the execution of this statement fails with the `NameError` shown.

Use the `!` command to *explicitly* execute a Python statement when the statement can be recognized as a debugger command.

```
(Pdb) ! a = pos_fram.columns[-1]
(Pdb) ! b = pos_frame[a].values
```

(In general, use `!` unless you *know* it isn't necessary. `x` is not a debugger command, so there is no ambiguity whether `x = 4` is a debugger command or a Python statement to execute.)